# Comparing binomials raised to the 8th power

Tags: binomial-theorem, gre-exam

The following is from a practice GRE question. I was hoping if anyone could tell me if I have reached the right conclusion for the right reasons.

The question is as follows:

> Given that ab = 0, which value is greater?
>
> A) (a + b)^8
>
> B) (a - b)^8
>
> C) Answers A & B are equal
>
> D) Cannot be determined

I calculated this as follows:

(a-b)^8 = ((a-b)^2)^4

= ((a^2 - 2ab + b^2))^4

= ((a^2 - 0 + b^2))^4

= (a^2 + b^2)^4

---

(a+b)^8 = ((a+b)^2)^4

= ((a^2 + 2ab + b^2))^4

= ((a^2 + 0 + b^2))^4

= (a^2 + b^2)^4

---

Therefore, A & B both evaluate to (a^2 + b^2)^4 and the correct answer is C.

Comment: Yes and Yes....

Comment: Though if time is an element of the context for this question, the best exam technique might me to note that any even power of real numbers is positive...

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to see this is that $ab = 0$ implies $a=0$ or $b=0$. In the first case you have $(0+b)^8 = (0-b)^8$. In the second case, $(a+0)^8 = (a-0)^8$.